# internal pypi repo with poetry and cdk synth

Tags: docker, github-actions, aws-cdk, python-poetry

**Long story short**:

Building a python lambda layer with poetry with a package from an internal repo fails in GitHub action fails with:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypackage==0.1.1 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for mypackage==0.1.1

**Context**:

I am using GitHub actions to deploy a python lambda with aws cdk.

My GitHub actions steps are roughly:

- install npm, cdk and dependencies
- install python, poetry and dependencies, including the dependency in my private repo
- run all tests/linter...
- cdk bootstrap

Up to here, all is fine.

The next step, `cdk synth`, fails.

The step looks like:

```yaml
- name: CDK Synth
  env:
    POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.relevant_secret }}
    POETRY_HTTP_BASIC_INTERNAL_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.other_relevant_secret }}
  run: |
    npx aws-cdk synth --validation --verbose
```

Note that giving the variables like this is confirmed in the poetry step before in the process, which does not involve cdk.

The layer directory of the lambda has a `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock`, which are copied from the previous poetry step, so guaranteed to work as well. The relevant lines are:

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
mypackage = {version="*", source = "internal"}
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal"
url = "..."
priority = "explicit"
```

**Question**:
How can I pass the credentials to the `cdk synth` command (docker in the background)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite a ride, but here is what happens.

The cdk supports a pyproject.toml (poetry.lock, actually) to build a layer, but uses it to export to requirements.txt. During this export, the extra source information was lost.

So now I build my own requirements.txt, in the following way:

```bash
req=src/lambda_layers/requirements.txt
echo "--extra-index-url https://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@$(poetry source show internal --no-ansi | grep url | grep -Po 'https://\K(.*)$')" > $req
poetry export --without=dev --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt >> $req
```

Then `synth` works.

Comment: Make sure to open an issue in the CDK GitHub repository.